# rails-boilerplate (0.1.9) gem mirror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem, bundler

Using paperclip (3.2.0)

Using polyamorous (0.5.0)

Using pr_geohash (1.0.0)

Using slop (3.3.3)

Using pry (0.9.10)

Using pry-rails (0.2.2)

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: too many connection resets (http://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/gems/rails-boilerplate-0.1.9.gem)
>   An error occurred while installing rails-boilerplate (0.1.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install rails-boilerplate -v '0.1.9'` succeeds before bundling.

Today, I applied bundle install in my rails directory, but i found out that the mirror where i get the gem rails-boilerplate is not available now? HOw can i modify the references of the mirror? I have tried:

> gem install --source http://rubygems.org/downloads rails-boilerplate

but it also failed.

Answer (score 0):

gem install rails-boilerplate -v '0.1.9'

Worked just fine for me.  My sources are:

```
gem sources -l
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
```

In general, all stable gem releases should be there even if the project is hosted on Github or elsewhere.  If you need to grab a different fork of it or a pre-release version, you may have to specify a different source, but in your case 0.1.0 looks like the current release version.  Somehow your gem source is set to fetch from

```
http://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/gems/rails-boilerplate-0.1.9.gem
```

What do you get when you run

```
gem sources -l
```

Since you get the error when installing directly with gem and when running bundle, I assume that the problem is in your default gem sources.  You should check the source list with the command above, and alter the list with

```
gem sources -r SOURCE_URI
```

to remove, or

```
gem sources -a SOURCE_URI
```

to add a new one.  I don't know if you should leave the http://tokyo-m.rubygems.org source there or not - it depends on if you have some nonstandard version of a gem installed from there or not.  If you do, I would suggest adding that source in your Gemfile, NOT as your gem source.  This can be done with something like this:

```
gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', 
    '0.0.0', 
    :git => 'git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
```

in your Gemfile.  Good luck!